# Can two paths with different end points be homotopic to each other?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I'm watching [this video](https://youtu.be/mzX-DLxsVwM?si=SelcjAixFasSPTfS) about fundamental groups. Around minute 3:20 if I have understood it well, the lecturer says that two paths with different end points can't be homotopic, right? If so, why is this true? I have no clue how to prove it.

EDIT: the definition I'm using of homotopic maps is the following: two continuous maps $f,g: X \to Y$ are said to be homotopic if there exist a family of continuous functions $h_t: X \to Y$ for $t\in [0,1]$ such that $h_0=f$ and $h_1=g$ and the map $h:X \times [0,1] \to Y,\, (x,t) \to h_t(x) $.

Comment: You should include your definition of a homotopy. The equivalence relation on curves in the definition of $\pi_1$ (or more generally the fundamental groupoid) is not homotopy, but homotopy with fixed endpoints.

Comment: There are various flavors of homotopy, and different kinds would give different answers to your question.

Comment: @Randall, I am mainly interested in understanding the remark given by the professor in the video (started at time ~ 3:25)

Comment: The definition in the video clearly states that endpoints must be fixed, but that's not what you've stated in your definition in the question.

Comment: In a previous video, this professor defined homotopy of maps exactly as I wrote it in my question. And this video he says that in order to define homotopy between paths we should change a bit the previous definition but I didn't understand his argument why we should do so !

Comment: OK, but that's a different question than the one you asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the lecturer says that two paths with different end points can't be homotopic, right?

No, the lecturer does not claim such thing. In fact he says something exactly opposite.

The most general definition of homotopy is the one you've provided. And in this sense two paths with different end points can be homotopic. In fact $[0,1]$ is contractible and therefore any two paths are homotopic (well, at least if the target space is path connected). Moreover the lecturer says the same thing. And the conclusion here is that this case is simply not interesting at all.

Then the lecturer defines "homotopy of paths" which is a term on its own, not just general homotopy connecting two paths. Yes, mathematics is a funny science where such nuances occure. Homotopy of paths is the usual homotopy with the additional condition that endpoints are fixed at every $t\in[0,1]$. And for that to work original paths have to share endpoints of course. In other words homotopy of paths is not even defined for paths with different endpoints, so the question "are those path homotopic" is meaningless.

And so there are two different definitions of homotopy in play here. And it turns out that this stronger notion is in many cases better, more useful.

Note that sometimes people use the term "free homotopy" for the general one, to emphasize that it does not fix points.

And remember to read theorems, proofs and claims carefully. Because the difference between homotopy and homotopy of paths seems small, but actually is very important.

Comment: Thank you so much @freakish .